# Make a toolbar with menu icon like amazon app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I am trying to make a toolbar with menu icon like amazon app. But the toolbar menu icon have not set properly. Actually All menu icon has set Left to right. i have need back icon and navigation icon has set on right side, App logo set on center and other icon has set on left side.

[image]

menu code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/action_back"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/texttite"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="102"
        android:title="@string/action_forward"
        android:titleCondensed="hello........"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_forward"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/action_forward"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bookmark1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="104"

        android:title="@string/action_bookmark"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

I have need this type of toolbar. I try this, but not success. Please Help me...

[image]

Comment: You have to add views to toolbar (design toolbar). You cannot use menu inflation in order to get a toolbar like amazon app.

Comment: how to using it ,please give example..

Comment: why don't you inflate a custom layout in toolbar or use custom layout in place of toolbar

Comment: Sir, please give example ..

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the toolbar layout just like any other layouts according to your requirement. Please find below a sample layout just using buttons.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="<" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="=" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Custom"
                    android:textColor="@color/backgroundColorGenericWhite"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="=" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your answers. But i used menu item , not button.

Answer (score 0):

this is custom toolbar code

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:padding="0px"
                android:layout_margin="0px"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```